# PHP won't work inline with HTML elements

Tags: php, html, searchbar

Can anybody help explain why I can't get PHP to work when using it inline with HTML elements?

- My file is saved as .php
- Yes, PHP is working on my server (I'm using XAMPP)
- Yes, PHP works when I use it outside of an HTML element (in a regular PHP block of code) but won't work when using it inline in my HTML

The following code is how I'm trying to implement the PHP code into my HTML. It can be found inside the first `input` of the form.

```
<li id="navHeaderItem" class="navHeaderItem headerSearchBar">
    <form action="./results.php" method="get" id="headerSearch" class="headerSearch">
        <input type="text" name="input" size="30" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET ['input']); ?>" placeholder="Search E-Shout!" id="headerSearchBar" class="headerSearchBar" />
        <input type="submit" value="Search" id="headerSearchButton" class="headerSearchButton" />
    </form>
</li>
```

Just to clarify my primary objective, I'm trying to create a basic search bar which will allow users to search the content of a site I'm working on. I'm watching a YouTube video (which can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uPW-Lpil5CU)) and the guy in the video is doing exactly the same thing with his PHP script.... (If you skip to 8:35 by clicking [here](https://youtu.be/uPW-Lpil5CU?t=8m35s) then you can see exactly how his code looks with the PHP inline.) But his works.....so I don't understand what's going on.

It doesn't help that I know very little about PHP....

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** Here is what it looks like as of right now....

[image]

Comment: What happens currently? Does your url have `?input=something` in it, or a `&input=something` if there are multiple values? Not going to enter the XSS topic here yet..

Comment: Add the attribute value to the input i.e. value="<?php echo $_GET ['input']; ?>"

Comment: I've added the PHP script into the value instead, so that brought back my search bar and everything in my header (the black bar at the top) which hadn't been showing before, but it displays an error message inside the search bar now: `<br /><b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: input in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\websites\E-Shout\results.php</b> on line <b>76</b><br />`. The PHP script in the body of my site still isn't giving me anything either. See my edited question for a picture of what it looks like at this point.

Comment: OK, it looks like, the main problem is that the mysql connection is misconfigured, check user, pwd, database

Comment: So you're saying my next step should be to go make sure my user, password, and database are correctly configured in the MySQL connection? I'm very knew to PHP and MySQL so I'm beating my head every step of the way trying to figure stuff out on my own and find answers/help/guidance online..

Comment: Actually the MySQL connection problem is caused by usage of the obsolete `mysql_connect` function. You're using PHP 7, where these functions have been removed, triggering the fatal error. Use alternatives such as `mysqli` or `PDO` instead.

For your main concern, apart from the advice from the first comment (you should really check if you're getting GET data), show us the code block from line 114-118 (better if 110-120) so that we can check those errors as well.

Comment: @Revenant should I place `mysqli` in place of `mysql` in every instance that `mysql` appears? I'm very new to PHP so all of this stuff is a lot for me to try and make sure I'm getting right. Lol.

Comment: That works most of the time, but I suggest you check the documentation for that function first.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET ['input']); ?>"  name="input" size="30" placeholder="Search E-Shout!" id="headerSearchBar" class="headerSearchBar" />
```

You need `htmlspecialchars()` as well because if you're not using it, a double quote in the input may break the html sytax

Comment: I've updated my code and my original post with your suggestion. It hasn't solved my problem but I'm sure it's one step out of the with many to go. Lol. Messing with languages you aren't used to can really be a hassle... (^_^;)

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the "Undefined index: input..." error, you have to check if $_GET['input'] exists. If exists, print its value. If not, print an empty string:

```
<input type="text" 
       name="input" 
       size="30" 
       value="<?php echo isset($_GET ['input']) ? htmlspecialchars($_GET ['input']) : ''; ?>" 
       placeholder="Search E-Shout!" 
       id="headerSearchBar" 
       class="headerSearchBar" />
```